# In Squarespace 7.1 I am trying to show one section and hide others- not working

Tags: jquery, css, squarespace

I am trying to implement a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_fvE8mO1ic&t=26s from Will Myers

in squarespace 7.1

You can view my live page here. https://www.thesquaresandbox.com/tabbed-sections
When I click a tab button, the correct section appears but the other two sections should be hidden but they are not. TIA

```
<script>
 
  function tabOneClick() {
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(1)').addClass("active");
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(2)').removeClass("active");
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(3)').removeClass("active");  
    
    $('[data-section-id="6069af192a871859f3dddfc3"]').addClass("tab-section-show");
    $('[data-section-id="6069af0fd446556b94c10177"]').removeClass("tab-section-show");
    $('[data-section-id="6069bad471b2824d888bdf66"]').removeClass("tab-section-show");
    
  }
  
  
  function tabTwoClick() {
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(1)').removeClass("active");
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(2)').addClass("active");
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(3)').removeClass("active");
    
    $('[data-section-id="6069af192a871859f3dddfc3"]').removeClass("tab-section-show");
    $('[data-section-id="6069af0fd446556b94c10177"]').addClass("tab-section-show");
    $('[data-section-id="6069bad471b2824d888bdf66"]').removeClass("tab-section-show");
  }
  
  
  function tabThreeClick() {
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(1)').removeClass("active");
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(2)').removeClass("active");
    $('button.tab-btn:nth-of-type(3)').addClass("active");
    
    $('[data-section-id="6069af192a871859f3dddfc3"]').removeClass("tab-section-show");
    $('[data-section-id="6069af0fd446556b94c10177"]').removeClass("tab-section-show");
    $('[data-section-id="6069bad471b2824d888bdf66"]').addClass("tab-section-show");
  }
  
  
  $(function() {
    $('[data-section-id="6069af192a871859f3dddfc3"]').addClass("tab-section-hide");
    $('[data-section-id="6069af0fd446556b94c10177"]').addClass("tab-section-hide");
    $('[data-section-id="6069bad471b2824d888bdf66"]').addClass("tab-section-hide");
    tabOneClick();
  });
</script>
```

```css
.tabs-container{
  transform:translateY(100%);
  width:100% !important;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index:99;
}
.tab-btn{
  max-width:150px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
  border:1px solid #999;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  font-size:1.2em;
  background:white;
  margin-bottom:none !important;
  border:none !important;
  &:not(:first-of-type){
  margin-left:10px;    
  }
}
.tab-btn.active{
  background:lightblue;
}

.tab-section-hide{
  display:none;
}
.tab-section-show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">
  <button class="tab-btn" id="tab-1" onclick="tabOneClick()">
    About
  </button>
  <button class="tab-btn" id="tab-2" onclick="tabTwoClick()">
    Gallery
  </button>
  <button class="tab-btn" id="tab-3" onclick="tabThreeClick()">
    Contact
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is using a rather inefficient, repetitive and frankly naive approach. At the very least, I'd simplify the approach and do the following, which doesn't require JQuery and avoids having to repeat the same code for each tab. You can leave your HTML and CSS as-is, though it could be simplified as well.

```
<script>
// Wrap code in a function to prevent adding vars to global scope.
(function() {
  // Store references to the tab container and the tab sections.
  var tabContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs-container")[0];
  var tabSections = document.querySelectorAll(
    'section[data-section-id="6069af192a871859f3dddfc3"],' +
    'section[data-section-id="6069af0fd446556b94c10177"],' +
    'section[data-section-id="6069bad471b2824d888bdf66"]'
  );
  var tabs;
  
  // Don't go any further if either of the above elements aren't found.
  if (!tabContainer || tabSections.length < 1) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Store a reference to all the individual tabs.
  tabs = tabContainer.children;
  
  // When the tab container is clicked, show the corresponding content.
  //  - Uses event delegation to avoid adding an event listener to every tab.
  //  - Gets the index of the tab that was clicked, and uses that index to set active and inactive content.
  tabContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tab = e.target;
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tabs, tab);
    tabSections.forEach(function(t) {
      if (Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tabs, t) == index) {
        tab.classList.add("active");
      }
      else {
        tab.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  });
  
  // Click the first tab.
  tabs[0].click();
})();
</script>
```

Note that the above code assumes that there is only one tabbed UI on any given page and that the sections are listed in the order corresponding to the tabs.

Be aware that, when it comes to Squarespace, most of the tutorials and code snippets out there are written by individuals with relatively little JavaScript experience. That is not to say they are not a reasonable place to start, but having an awareness of that may help you along the way.